# NSString to wchar_t or #define

Tags: objective-c

I've to define ios application path as constant so how should I set PATH constant programmatically.
Following is the snippet:

```
NSString *dirPath = @"/var/mobile/Applications/7BCC7E9C-18DE-4AFD-A7BA-9E8070D39161/Documents/" ;
```

How to set this dirPath to following

```
#define PATH L"/var/mobile/Applications/7BCC7E9C-18DE-4AFD-A7BA-9E8070D39161/Documents/"
```

or
set to wchar_t:

```
      wchar_t *path = dirPath;
```

Comment: do you want current path of your app? use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]`

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or even:

```
#define DOCUMENT_DIR [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
```

Comment: I've tried this #define PATH appDelegate.fileDirectoryPath; But still not working. L is not there. Better if I convert it into wchar_t. but how?

Comment: you should probably remove the semicolon from the macro.

Comment: There is need to add L e.g. #define PATH L"appDelegate.fileDirectoryPath"

Answer (score 0):

```
// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```